# Unity WebGL Metamask Connection - nethereumUnityInstance is not defined in javascript

Tags: transactions, connection, metamask, unity-webgl, nethereum

I tried to connect Metamask wallet to Unity WebGL.
Here is the github sample project link that I refered.

https://github.com/Nethereum/Nethereum.Unity.Webgl

I installed the same version of Unity to let the sample project work properly.

- Unity Version : 2021.2.13f1
- Microsoft Visual Studio : 2022

I built and run the project.

[This is the build settings window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zllYl.png)

After running, there was not any problem.

I click the [Connect] button

[And the Metamask extension window popped up as like other Metamask wallet connections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMGZz.png)

After connect to the Metamask I continuously got this error.

[This is the image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugYOc.png)

[This is the image of browser javascript console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZT7U.png)

[This is the place in build folder where the error is originally occured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hF0qm.png)

I do not know why this happeneds.
I manually followed the sample project.

I have to connect Metamask to Unity WebGL.
And I have to run a transaction via an account that is connected to Unity WebGL.

Could anybody help me?
Could anybody give me alternative option to connect and run a transaction ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit the index.html to add **nethereumUnityInstance = unityInstance;**

```
createUnityInstance(canvas, config, (progress) => {
    progressBarFull.style.width = 100 * progress + "%";
}).then((unityInstance) => {
  nethereumUnityInstance = unityInstance;
  loadingBar.style.display = "none";
  fullscreenButton.onclick = () => {
    unityInstance.SetFullscreen(1);
  };
})
```

There is a github issue about it here: [GitHub Nethereum #5](https://github.com/Nethereum/Nethereum.Unity.Webgl/issues/5)